# babelでtypescriptをコンパイルするのとtscでtypescriptをコンパイルするのにどのような違いがありますか？

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

babelでもpluginを用いればtypescriptをコンパイルできますが、tscを用いてコンパイルするのとは何が違うのでしょうか？

jsとtsが混在していてもtypescriptのtsconfigで `allowJs` を有効にすればtscでjavascriptもtypescriptもコンパイルできるので、素人目にはほとんど同じことができるような気がしています。

tscだとなにか困ることがあるからできるのだと思うのですが、調べきることができませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

英単語で検索したら一発でした。

[Choosing between Babel and TypeScript - LogRocket Blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/choosing-between-babel-and-typescript-4ed1ad563e41/)

そこにTypeScriptを使用する際に知らなくてもいいようなことまで違いが詳しく書いてあるようです。
大きな違いはBabelは型チェックをしないことでしょう。

型チェックの説明が必要ですか？
TypeScriptのtscで型チェックを体験してみてください。
体験したらわかると思います。